# I don't have any special plans for this weekend

Tags: prepositions, parts-of-speech, parsing

1. I don't have any special plans for this weekend.

---

Q1: What is the meaning of 'for' here?
Q2: What is the part of speech of 'for this weekend'? Does it modify 'any special plans'? Or does it modify 'don't have'?

Answer (score 3):

In OP's context, including the preposition strongly implies that ***for this weekend*** should be interpreted as an "adjectival" element modifying the plural noun *[special] **plans***.

Without the preposition, ***this weekend*** is an "adverbial" element modifying the verb *[to] **have** [plans]*.

In practice, it doesn't really make any difference to the overall *meaning* in the exact cited context, but there could be a difference in, say,...

> 1: *I paid the bill **for** last week*
>    2: *I paid the bill last week*

...where exactly the same *syntactic* distinction applies.

In #1 it's the ***bill*** that relates to [goods / services delivered] last week - which might be ***paid for*** later.

In #2, it's the ***act of paying*** that happened last week, where ***last week*** adverbially modifies the verb-based action *[to] **pay** [the bill]*.

---

It may help to note that it's *not* possible to say *I **am paying** the bill last week*, but it *is* perfectly natural to say *I am paying **last week's bill*** or *I am paying **the bill for last week***.